# Is it a Projective R-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra

> **R** is a commutative ring with unity.
>
> Let $\textbf{P}$ be a finitely generated projective $\textbf{R[t]}$-module. Then is $\textbf{P/$t^n$P}$ a finitely generated projective $\textbf{R}$-module?

Now in my attempt I have desperately tried using the idempotent lifting of projective module but I have failed miserably, it seems that I am missing something very simple.

$\textbf{Idempotent Lifting}$ : If **I** is a nilpotent ideal or a **complete ideal** then there is a bijection between isomorphism classes of finitely generated projective mdules over **R** and finitely generated projective modules over **R/I**.

So here in the ring **R[t]/($t^n$)** I have $(t)+(t^n)$ as a nilpotent ideal and **R[t]/(t)** $\cong$ **R**. I was thinking along this line. If you could help me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $P$ is a finitely generated projective $R[t]$-module, it is (isomorphic to) a direct summand  of some finitely generated free $R[t]$-module, say $R[t]^s$, so , tensoring with $R[t]/(t^n)$ over $R[t]$, we obtain that $P/t^nP$ is a direct summand of 
$$R[t]^s\otimes_{R[t]}R[t]/(t^n)\simeq \bigl(R[t]/(t^n)\bigr)^{\!s}$$
and each factor of the latter is a finitely generated free $R$-module

Answer (score 1):

**P** is finitely generated projective **R[t]** module
$\Rightarrow$ there is a **R[t]** module **Q** such that **P$\oplus$Q**  = **R$[t]^s$**

Now take **P** $\otimes$**R[t]/($t^n$)**$\oplus$ **Q** $\otimes$**R[t]/($t^n$)**

this is $\cong$ to $(\textbf{R[t]}/(t^n))^s$

Now $\textbf{R[t]}/(t^n) $ has a basis set {$1$, $t$, $t^2$,.....$t^{n-1}$} thus it is a free **R** module.